# Format string to date format swift

Tags: swift, date, datetime, swift3

How can I format below string to date format

1. "Wed Feb 27 22:18:38 UTC 2019"
2. "2018-10-31"

I need both strings in dd/MM/YYYY format.

Comment: sorry @matt . let me know how can i turn that into date?

Comment: Use date formatter, set the locale to `"en_US_POSIX`" and use a fixed date format. In your case `"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to changes the format for working in both case:

```
    var isoDate = "2018-10-31"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    print(dateFormatter.date(from: isoDate)!)

    isoDate = "2016-04-14T10:44:00+0000"
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZZZ"
    print(dateFormatter.date(from: isoDate)!)
```